# How to disable images from being viewed in the browser?

Tags: css, image, background

I've noticed that most of the websites now "somehow" disable viewing some of the images used in their template, so I'd like to obtain this same result:

[image]

I thought instead of using the tag `<a>`with `<img>`, I put a div and set the "background" property as an image yet it's still viewable in the browser!!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not disabling the images, this is done by using [images as backgrounds](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp) in CSS and not as a normal img tag like:`<img src="your-image.jpg" />`.
 **[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/s7ese9aw/)** how this is done:

HTML

```
<div class="randomClass"></div>
```

And the CSS goes like this:

```
.randomClass {
    background-image: url('http://i.ytimg.com/vi/1WmaBpkGjXk/mqdefault.jpg');
    background-color: #cccccc;
    width:350px;
    height: 180px;
}
```

On the **[Jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/s7ese9aw/)** I provided above if you right click on the 1st image you have the option to open the image on a new page or the option to download it. On the second one you don't have this options by right clicking on it, but still these images can be downloaded in other ways.